# Show that each number of $100!+1,100!+2,100!+3,...,100!+100$ is composite

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm working in the following Wilson's theorem excercise:

> Show that each number of $100!+1,100!+2,100!+3,...,100!+100$ is composite number.

I'm starting from:
$$100! \equiv -1 \pmod {101}$$

My thoughts about this is that I may be able to add the required number each time to that congruence, so for the first case I would have:

$$100! +1\equiv (-1)(+1) \pmod {101}$$
$$100! +1\equiv 0 \pmod {101}$$

Showing that $101k=100!+1$ so $100!+1$ is a composite number and I would basically do the same for each number.

Is that correct? Am I missing something? Any hint, help or correction will be really appreciated.

Comment: for $k \in \{2,3,\cdots,n\} \, \, n!+k$ is divisible by $k$

Comment: Do you mean **composite** number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$101$ is prime so by Wilson's theorem $100!\equiv -1\pmod {101}$ so $100!+1\equiv 0\pmod {101} $ so $101|100!+1$ .

For $1 <k\le 100$ we simply note the $k|100! $ (by definition) and $k|k $ so $k|100!+k $.

Note $N! +1$ *might* be prime for some $N $ but not if $N+1$ is prime.  $3!+1=7$ is prime (but $3+1$ isnt).

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Wilson's theorem. If $1<k\leq n$ then ${n!\over k}\in \mathbb{N}$ and we have:

$$ n!+k = k \cdot \underbrace{({n!\over k}+1)}_{>1}$$

Comment: Like @greedoid pointed out, you can factor $k$ in each term $n!+k$. The only case apparently left out is $100! +1$.

Comment: But why care about that case? What do you want to prove?

Comment: Because the task is to prove that $100! +1, 100! + 2, \cdots 100! + 100$ are all composed. In particular you must also show that $100!+1$ is composed and your argument by itself does not guarantee that.